# Multiple activities and put result on the last activity

Tags: android

In my android application suppose several activities are there if using intent I go to other activities like this.

If user choose correct answer on Activity A, it will bring to Activity C

```
[Activity A]->[activity C]
```

else, user choose the wrong answer in activity A, it will bring the user to activity B before going to Activity C

```
[Activity A]->[activity B]->[Activity C]
```

Activity C acts to show the result.

However, when I write code in Activity C to appear result. The result did not show bring me back to Activity A again.

```
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Solution);
    ImageView imagee = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.solutionImage);
    String cconection = getIntent().getStringExtra("SpinConnection");//get from Activity B
    String ccondition = getIntent().getStringExtra("SpinCondition");//Get from Activity B
    String txtPowerSupply = getIntent().getStringExtra("PowerCable"); //get from Activity A

    if (txtPowerSupply.equals("PowerOff")) {

        text.setText("A+");
        imagee.setImageResource(R.drawable.sakura);
    }

    if (cconection.equals("Not properly connected") && ccondition.equals("Good")) {
    text.setText("B+");
    imagee.setImageResource(R.drawable.sakura); }
```

---

Activity A

```
               switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.PowerOn:
            if (checked)
            {
                Intent monpage = new Intent(ActivityA.this, com.example.lenovo.computerhardwarediagnostic.ActivityB.class);
                startActivity(monpage);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.PowerOff:
            if (checked) {
                //Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Solution.class);
                //int genderID = powerSupply.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                Intent data = new Intent(ActivityA.this, com.example.lenovo.computerhardwarediagnostic.ActivityC.class);
                data.putExtra("PowerCable","PowerOff");
                startActivity(data);
               finish();
            }
            break;
        }
```

---

Activity B

```
            if(fact1.equalsIgnoreCase("Not properly connected")&&fact2.equalsIgnoreCase("Good"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
                intent.putExtra("SpinConnection","Not properly connected");
                intent.putExtra("SpinCondition","Good");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
```

I'm a beginner in Android. Can you help me to solve this?

Comment: Show your code that does `intent.putExtra` please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can only retrieve the intent that initiated `ActivityC`, so the information stored in the intent sent by `ActivityA` is lost.

In `ActivityB` extract the information from `ActivityA` and pass it to `ActivityC`.

Try this:

---

In Activity A

```
               switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.PowerOn:
            if (checked)
            {
                Intent monpage = new Intent(ActivityA.this, com.example.lenovo.computerhardwarediagnostic.ActivityB.class);

                //Pass the info to ActivityB
                monpage.putExtra("PowerCable","PowerOn");

                startActivity(monpage);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.PowerOff:
            if (checked) {
                //Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Solution.class);
                //int genderID = powerSupply.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                Intent data = new Intent(ActivityA.this, com.example.lenovo.computerhardwarediagnostic.ActivityC.class);
                data.putExtra("PowerCable","PowerOff");
                startActivity(data);
               finish();
            }
            break;
        }
```

---

Activity B

```
if(fact1.equalsIgnoreCase("Not properly connected")&&fact2.equalsIgnoreCase("Good"))
            {
                //getting info from ActivityA
                String powerCableValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("PowerCable");

                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
                //passing info to ActivityC
                intent.putExtra("PowerCable",powerCableValue);

                intent.putExtra("SpinConnection","Not properly connected");
                intent.putExtra("SpinCondition","Good");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
```

Comment: I didn't see that you have two different intents, try again adding line `monpage.putExtra("PowerCable","PowerOn");` I edited the post with this update.